# Gradient flows: is this a typo in a discretization scheme?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, hilbert-spaces, gradient-flows

I'm reading below theorem from [this](https://www.math.leidenuniv.nl/%7Evangaans/TA2011-gradient-mei11.pdf) lecture note.

---

**Theorem 4.5.** Let $H$ be a Hilbert space over $\mathbb{R}$. If $\varphi: H \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is differentiable and convex, then for every $u \in H$ there exists a unique $y:[0, \infty) \rightarrow H$ such that
$$
\begin{aligned}
& y^{\prime}(t)=-\nabla \varphi(y(t)), \quad t \geq 0, \\
& y(0)=u.
\end{aligned}
$$

**Idea of proof.** Fix $h>0$. Discretize the differential equation with Euler's implicit scheme,
$$
\frac{y((n+1) h)-y(n h)}{h}=-\nabla \varphi(\color{red}{y(n h)}) .
$$
Then, with $y_n=y(n h)$,
$$
y_{n+1}+h \nabla \varphi\left(\color{red}{y_{n+1}}\right)=y_n,
$$
so that
$$
y_{n+1}=(I+h \nabla \varphi)^{-1}\left(y_n\right) .
$$
One of the difficulties is to show that the function $x \mapsto x+h \nabla \varphi(x)$ is invertible. Then
$$
J_h(x):=(I+h \nabla \varphi)^{-1}(x), \quad x \in H,
$$
is called the resolvent associated to $\nabla \varphi$. We obtain
$$
y_n=J_h^n(u),
$$
and this is hoped to be a good approximation for $y(n h)$. The next steps are to show that
$$
y(t):=\lim _{k \rightarrow \infty} J_{t / k}^n(u)
$$
exists and that the function $y$ thus defined is the unique solution.

---

**My understanding** It seems to me
$$
\frac{y((n+1) h)-y(n h)}{h}=-\nabla \varphi(\color{red}{y(n h)})
$$
implies $y_{n+1}+h \nabla \varphi\left(\color{red}{y_{n}}\right)=y_n$, and **not** $y_{n+1}+h \nabla \varphi\left(\color{red}{y_{n+1}}\right)=y_n$ as written in the lecture note. Then it should be $y_{n}=(I-h \nabla \varphi)^{-1}\left(y_{n+1}\right)$.

> Could you confirm if my understanding is correct, or I miss something else?

Comment: Since they said Euler's implicit scheme, it should be $-\nabla\varphi(y_{n + 1})$ instead; see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backward_Euler_method

Comment: @CheeHan This solves my confusion. Could you post your comment as an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the author mentioned Euler's implicit scheme (i.e., [Backward Euler's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backward_Euler_method)), the approximation should be, with $y_n\colon = y(nh)$,
$$ \frac{y_{n + 1} - y_n}{h} = -\nabla\varphi(y_{n + 1}). $$